# Conjugate of composition in Bochner spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, convex-optimization, convexity, convex-analysis, duality

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space (of non-zero dimension), let $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a finite measure space, and let $L^2(\mu;H)$ be the Bochner-space $\mu$-integrable $H$-valued functions.  Consider proper, lower semi-continuous, and convex functions $\phi:H\rightarrow (-\infty,\infty)$ and $\psi:L^2(\mu;\mathbb{R})\rightarrow (-\infty,\infty]$ and define the map:
$$
L^2(\mu;H) \ni f(\omega) \mapsto \Phi(f)(\omega) \in L^2(\mu;\mathbb{R});
$$
and suppose that $\Phi$ is Frechet differentiable and coercive on all of $H$.

Can the convex conjugate $(\psi\circ \Phi)^{\star}$ be expressed in terms of $\psi$ and $\Phi$?